# How to set the jQuery ClassyLoader plugin to show the animation when sections are visible?

Tags: jquery

I used [classyLoader plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Circular-Percentage-Loader-Plugin-with-jQuery-Canvas-ClassyLoader/) for my project but it animates right after the page is loaded and you can not see the animation because it is not in the view yet.

And here is the [link of my project](https://rahulebi.000webhostapp.com/#skills).

Comment: Would you add the relevant code into your question, Asad? We discourage linking to the buggy project, since once that is fixed, the question will no longer make any sense.

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

You should put the following code

```js
function isvisible(el){
  return window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= el.offsetTop
}
window.onscroll=function(){
  var elem = document.getElementById("isHidden");
  if(isvisible(elem)){
    //You have to animate or create the element
    elem.style.background="orange"
  }
}
```

```css
p{
  height: 800px;
}
div{
  background: red;
  width 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<div id="isHidden"></div>
```

*According to your huge code put the following*

```
function isvisible(){
 return window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= $('.progressbar').parent()[0].offsetTop;
}
window.onscroll=function(){
  if(isvisible()){
    var loader = $('.loader').ClassyLoader({
    .........
  }
}
```